# Hashing strings for load balancing

Tags: python, string, function, hash, load-balancing

There's a great deal of information I can find on hashing strings for obfuscation or lookup tables, where collision avoidance is a primary concern.  I'm trying to put together a hashing function for the purpose of load balancing, where I want to fit an unknown set of strings into an arbitrarily small number of buckets with a relatively even distribution.  Collisions are expected (desired, even).

My immediate use case is load distribution in an application, where I want each instance of the application to fire at a different time of the half-hour, without needing any state information about other instances.  So I'm trying to hash strings into integer values from 0 to 29.  However, the general approach has wider application with different int ranges for different purposes.

Can anyone make suggestions, or point me to docs that would cover this little corner of hash generation?

My language of choice for this is python, but I can read most common langues so anything should be applicable.

Comment: Just take a modulus of any hash function.

Comment: Taking a modulus of any old hashing function doesn't work very well for even distribution.  Much like hashing for lookup tables, generating an even distribution works better in some hashing functions than in others.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I can provide a mathematical proof that you can't do better than taking the modulus of a sufficiently random-looking hash function unless you have some additional knowledge about the inputs - and the statistical distribution of the inputs isn't enough additional knowledge.

Comment: If you can't have a central server handle the load-balancing, you'll probably want to just have the instances generate random numbers for times to fire. That way, maliciously-constructed input won't be capable of generating load spikes.

Comment: Some testing with random chunks of a book from Project Gutenberg suggest that SLaks' idea does produce a fairly even distribution with Python's built-in `hash`. Check it out with a `collections.Counter`.

Answer (score 5):

Your might consider something simple, like the adler32() algo, and just mod for bucket size.

```
import zlib

buf = 'arbitrary and unknown string'

bucket = zlib.adler32(buf) % 30

# at this point bucket is in the range 0 - 29
```